# When to use a unit testing framework (vs. just using asserts)?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

Using a small (currently at 150 loc, probably less than 500 when finished) C project I'm working on, I'm teaching myself test driven development.  Based on some stuff I've found on the web - especially [these slides by Olve Maudal](http://olvemaudal.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/test-driven-development-in-c/), I've just been using asserts in my unit tests.

Since I'm just learning tdd, I have thus far avoided the overhead of also learning a unit testing framework such as cunit.  At this point, my thinking is that the additional learning curve - even if shallow - of a framework is not worth the effort for such a small project.  I'm wondering:  Is this incorrect (i.e. I'd be better off learning the framework now)?  At what point does learning a framework pay off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The break-even for learning a unit test framework is not long to reach. Two main advantages one gets with a framework over using assert() function are

- more detailed message for assertion failure: expected vs. actual value
- execution of all test cases in lieu of stopping on first failed assertion

The two of those give hints as to where the error is located.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience with learning .NET unit testing frameworks, I pretty much started with a small project which then gave me the advantage of being able apply what I'd learned to other projects later on, regardless of their size.

I guess you might be thinking what's the point, it's only a small bit of code, right now, but I think you would be doing well to get into a framework now rather then later. It's a bit like driving a car - I learned to drive when I was 17 years old, though I didn't get my own car until two years later. I could have just ignored taking lessons until I had got my car, but I passed and already had the skills to just go on and drive.

Bit of a weird analogy, but it's how I think when it comes to learning something like a framework, or library - you just never know what it will come in handy for you.

Answer (score 1):

Learn an xUnit framework - when you get onto programming larger scale commercial projects you'll find they are used extensively.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Most of my work is in scientific environments, and tends toward relatively small projects. However, I am leaning toward an xunit framework, especially since I'm likely to use others as I switch languages.

Answer (score 1):

> Since I'm just learning tdd, I have thus far avoided the overhead of also learning a unit testing framework such as cunit. At this point, my thinking is that the additional learning curve - even if shallow - of a framework is not worth the effort for such a small project. I'm wondering: Is this incorrect (i.e. I'd be better off learning the framework now)? At what point does learning a framework pay off?

I agree with philippe, Jason and Paolo, but wanted to throw in yet another way of looking at it:

The so-called [xUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit) frameworks are a **very** simple and light, both as a library to download (binaries of e.g. latest JUnit or CUnit are around 200 kilobytes), and, more imporantly, conceptually.

If you're doing (or would like to do) *any* unit testing at all, you would definitely benefit from using a proven tool, and learning xUnit will start paying off right away. I think you may have overestimated the "overhead" involved somewhat – don't let the word "framework" scare you ;-) – you'll be up and running with xUnit in half an hour or less.

<sup>Disclaimer: Your question isn't tagged C, so I took it as language-agnostic one. I don't know if unit testing is very different on C side (compared to Java), but I doubt it. :-)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Following is a C# .Net example where a `Moq framework` is useful in a MSTest using Visual Studio.

Observe the difference between `TestOld()` and `MoqTest()`. Purpose of both the tests are same. But in `TestOld()`, I need to write `MyMemberManagerForTest` concrete implementation. Whereas in `MoqTest()`, the Moq framework will do the task for me.

```
  _mockIMemberManager = new Mock<IMemberManager>();
  _mockIMemberManager.Setup(x => x.GetMember(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(member);
```

Reference: [How to Use Mock Library For Your Unit Testing In C#](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-Use-Mock-Library-f7af332b)

```
[TestClass()]
public class TestMembershipManager
{
    private LibraryCore _targetLibraryCore;

    #region Old Test withou Moq

    public class MyMemberManagerForTest : IMemberManager
    {
        public Member GetMember(int memberID)
        {
            Member member = new Member()
            {
                MemberID = 1,
                FirstName = "Lijo",
                MaximumBookCanBorrow = 4,
            };

            return member;
        }
    }

    private IMemberManager _memberManager;

    [TestMethod()]
    public void TestOld()
    {
        _memberManager = new MyMemberManagerForTest();
        _targetLibraryCore = new LibraryCore(_memberManager);

        int memberID = 1;
        double expected = 12;
        double actual;

        //TEST
        actual = _targetLibraryCore.CalculateMembershipCost(memberID);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }


    #endregion

    #region Test with Moq
    private Mock<IMemberManager> _mockIMemberManager;

    [TestMethod()]
    public void MoqTest()
    {
        _mockIMemberManager = new Mock<IMemberManager>();
        _targetLibraryCore = new LibraryCore(_mockIMemberManager.Object);

        Member member = new Member()
        {
            MemberID = 1,
            FirstName = "Lijo",
            MaximumBookCanBorrow = 4,
        };

        _mockIMemberManager.Setup(x => x.GetMember(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(member);

        int memberID = 1;
        double expected = 12;
        double actual;

        //TEST
        actual = _targetLibraryCore.CalculateMembershipCost(memberID);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

For this type of testing to work it is important for the code to utilize `Dependency Injection` as you can see in the overloaded LibraryCore constructor

```
public class LibraryCore
{
    private readonly IMemberManager _memberManager;

    public LibraryCore(IMemberManager memberManager)
    {
        this._memberManager = memberManager;
    }

    public double CalculateMembershipCost(int memberID)
    {
        double membershipCost = 0;
        Member member = _memberManager.GetMember(memberID);
        membershipCost = 10 + member.MaximumBookCanBorrow * 0.5;
        return membershipCost;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One note: if you are following the normal pattern of red-green-refactor, then as you refactor your unit tests, the resultant code should evolve towards being a unit test framework. For instance, you shouldn't have two copies of code that does

```
if (expected != actual) {printf("%d != %d", actual, expected); return -1;}
```

That should be refactored into something like

```
void AssertNotEqual(int expected, int actual, char* message)
{
    if (expected != actual) {printf(message, actual, expected); return -1;}
}
```